# Apply an iptables rule to a pcap file

Tags: python-3.x, iptables, pcap

I want to develop a simple firewall (for understanding and testing purposes) which would filter out packets which obey the rules in a sample iptables rule file (I found a sample rules file in here: https://www.rigacci.org/docs/biblio/online/nag-2.0.html/x-087-2-firewall.example.html)

Is there any library that supports this operation? Is there a way to apply rules in an iptables file to a pcap file.

Comment: There are 3 files in the link you've provided. Is this question regarding an iptables file or the output of `iptables -L $chain -v -n`? For either, can you provide the sample text in your question?